# Raspberry Pi VPN for accessing streaming services abroad with remote setup

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, raspberry-pi

I live in a European country which is different from another European country I grew up in. I would like to be able to access streaming services from my home country.

I am aware that there are VPN services which claim to offer the ability to watch these services abroad, however, they are often blocked by the streaming services.

I am wondering if it would be possible to set up a raspberry pi as a VPN so that I can send it to a non-tech savvy friend in my home country, and use their home network (non-static IP) as a VPN.

Is this something that could be possible to set up remotely (if for example I send the friend the pre-setup raspberry pi in the most)? Or would I need to set it up myself physically?

Answer (score 1):

I used the [PiVPN](https://www.pivpn.io/) installer script (I have no affiliation) to set up a Wireguard VPN on my Pi for a similar reason (to bypass filters at my school), as well as to access network resources on my home network. It isn't hard to set up remotely (it's a script that you would run over SSH), except you will need to make sure you can already access your Pi over SSH and be able to forward necessary ports for the VPN (which depending on your router, you might be able to using the w3m browser over SSH, or just have your friend do it).

Answer (score 1):

I don't own a raspberry pi but I recently did a similar project with an Ubuntu computer. My procedure, probably similar for a pi, was to set a wireguard server (really simple configuration), save a client configuration file for yourself and leave an SSH server running to troubleshoot any potential issues. Remember to set the service to autorun on startup.

When your friend receives it, they will have to open a port in their home router that points to your Pi and the port wireguard is listening to, and tell you their IP address. Connect and SSH to it, find out the subnet of their network, preferably set a static IP for your raspberry out of the DHCP of the network, and tell your friend to update the port mapping (all this should take about 10 minutes of their time). When you reconnect, SSH again to enable ipv4 forwarding through the interface and update your client to route all traffic through wireguard (AllowedIps:0.0.0.0/0). Remember to make the changes in the forwarding persistent across reboots too.

If their IP address changes frequently, I would use a provider such as noip to get an address which communicates with your pi to update the IP automatically, or create a bot which regularly checks and sends you a message if the IP changes (I made one a few days ago: https://github.com/alm059/telegram-bot).

There are quite a few steps and considerations, but I hope this general outline is clear and helps

Answer (score 0):

There is a product called VPNyWhere that was designed with this use case in mind.  It also includes other features like Nextcloud, Jitsi Meet and Pi-Hole.  Check it out at VPNyWhere.net